# Getting the mean of multiple axis of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

In numpy is there a fast way of calculating the mean across multiple axis? I am calculating the mean on all but the 0 axis of an n-dimensional array.

I am currently doing this;

```
for i in range(d.ndim - 1):
    d = d.mean(axis=1)
```

I'm wondering if there is a solution that doesn't use a python loop.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In numpy 1.7 you can give multiple axis to `np.mean`:

```
d.mean(axis=tuple(range(1, d.ndim)))
```

I am guessing this will perform similarly to the other proposed solutions, unless reshaping the array to flatten all dimensions triggers a copy of the data, in which case this should be much faster. So this is probably going to give a more consistent performance.

Comment: Excellent! I'm on numpy 1.6 currently though.

Comment: I cannot confirm that this feature exists, neither in version 1.7.1 or version 1.8.2 of numpy. Wishful thinking?

Comment: Have you tried it and it didn't work? It was there in 1.7, trust me. The change was made to all ufuncs, so it propagated automatically to all functions, like `np.mean`, that rely on `np.add`. It wasn't added to the docs of `mean` and other similar functions, although there is [an open PR](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5146) to fix that. But you can take a look at [the docs of `np.sum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5146) which were updated and have the relevant change tagged as *New in version 1.7.0.*

Comment: @Jamie D'oh! I had tried it, but with a `list` of integers, rather than a `tuple`, inspired by your example that uses `range` (which in Python 2.7 returns a list). In my opinion, the numpy functions should be indifferent to the type, supporting any iterable (list, tuple, range...). Until then, you should change your example so it actually works. =)

Answer (score 10):

My approach would be to reshape the array to flatten all of the higher dimensions and then run the mean on axis 1. Is this what your looking for?

```
In [14]: x = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])

In [16]: x.reshape((x.shape[0], -1)).mean(axis=1)
Out[16]: array([ 2.5,  6.5])
```

(step 2 just calculates the product of the lengths of the higher dims)

Comment: Thanks!  Also, -1 can be used instead of higher_dims.

Comment: @dsg101 awesome! Editing now!

Comment: For numpy 1.7 and newer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/17403375/2910092

Answer (score 3):

You can also use numpy.apply_over_axes:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]])
y = np.apply_over_axes(np.mean, x, (1, 2))
y = array([[[ 2.5]],[[ 6.5]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the suggestion of @dsg101, is this the sort of thing you want?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> d=np.reshape(np.arange(5*4*3),[5,4,3])
>>> d
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23]],

       [[24, 25, 26],
        [27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32],
        [33, 34, 35]],

       [[36, 37, 38],
        [39, 40, 41],
        [42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47]],

       [[48, 49, 50],
        [51, 52, 53],
        [54, 55, 56],
        [57, 58, 59]]])
>>> np.mean(np.reshape(d,[d.shape[0],np.product(d.shape[1:])]),axis=1)
array([  5.5,  17.5,  29.5,  41.5,  53.5])
```

Comment: Yes, I think this would be faster than the OP soln.

Comment: `np.product(d.shape[1:])` is better spelt `-1`